# Calculating gradient ascent vector from a scalar field

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics, vector-analysis, scalar-fields

For a computer program, given an `n`x`n` grid of scalar values (which can be viewed as a height field), I need to calculate the gradient at a point `P` therein, by sampling the 3x3 cells around `P` (its local cell neighbourhood).

To my rather naive thinking (calculus not being my strong point!), the below method *should* suffice: I take the average delta of each row (`x`) and each col (`y`) of the 3x3 neighbourhood:

```
0 x ->
y 4 1 0   1-4=-3, 0-1=-1, avg=-2.0
| 7 6 2   6-7=-1, 2-6=-4, avg=-2.5 
V 9 8 5   8-9=-1, 5-8=-3, avg=-2.0
  | | |
  | | \-  2-0=+2, 5-2=+3, avg=+2.5
  | \---  6-1=+5, 8-6=+2, avg=+3.5
  \-----  7-4=+3, 9-7=+2, avg=+2.5
```

Then I average these averages for `x` and `y` respectively (I could apply weighting to e.g. central row or column):

```
dx = (-2.0) + (-2.5) + (-2.0) = 6.5 / 3 = approx -2.17
dy = ( 2.5) + ( 3.5) + ( 2.5) = 8.5 / 3 = approx  2.83
```

So the resultant gradient ascent vector is `(-2.17, 2.83)`.

Besides averaging across a larger neighbourhood (5x5, 7x7 etc.), are there other / better / more precise ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact your evaluation is equal at each point to

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2}$$ with obvious notations and a similar computation for the other partial derivative. This is a good evaluation.

However, at each step you’re adding $f(x)$ and subtracting it, which is not efficient in term of computation.

Comment: Thank you. Are there other methods you would suggest, or is that the only really sane way of approaching it?

Comment: This is the best evaluation if you use a maximum of 3 equidistant points.

Comment: And if more than 3 equidistant points were used? Let's make this answer complete.

Comment: You should have a look at [numerical differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation). This is a topic by itself!